# Effeciently merging dataframe rows based on multiple columns and substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on analyzing sudo logs from a large number of *nix systems.  One issue I've run into is that every now and then someone runs a massively long command(typically a bunch of concatenated commands) and sudo logs it as multiple events in syslog due to event size limiations in both sudo and syslog, so I am trying to find a good way to reassemble the full command.

I am pulling the data out of my SIEM and loading it into a dataframe, and I'm able to easily parse out the necessary columns(eg: account, server, command, etc...), however I am running into an issue flattening/combining the commands.

The following code works, but is painfully slow on a large number of records.

```
# Load some dummy data
data = [
        ["1694030392144", "server1", "bob" , "/home/bob/", "command=a bunch of commands here; "        ],
        ["1694030392145", "server1", "bob" , "/home/bob/", "(command continued) more commands here; "  ],
        ["1694030392146", "server1", "bob" , "/home/bob/", "(command continued) even commands here; "  ],
        ["1694030392147", "server1", "bob" , "/home/bob/", "(command continued) yet more commands here"],
        ["1694030392148", "server9", "bob" , "/home/bob/", "(command continued) WTF"                   ],
        ["1694030392149", "server2", "bob" , "/home/bob/", "command=a new command"                     ],
        ["1694030392150", "server3", "bob" , "/home/bob/", "command=I did something; "                 ],
        ["1694030392151", "server3", "bob" , "/home/bob/", "(command continued) I did another thing"   ],
        ["1694030392152", "server2", "fred", "/"         , "command=a new command"                     ],
        ["1694030392153", "server1", "todd", "/tmp/"     , "command=I did something; "                 ],
        ["1694030392154", "server1", "todd", "/tmp/"     , "(command continued) I did another thing"   ]
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['epoch', 'server', 'account', 'pwd', 'command'])
# Data is typically in the correct order when loaded, but sorting just to be safe.
df.sort_values(['account','server','epoch'], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

FirstLoop = True
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # If the server or account changed, or it begins with "command =" again...
    if  curServer != row["server"] or curAccount != row["account"] or 
        row['command'].startswith("command=") == True:
        if FirstLoop == True:
            FirstLoop = False
        else:
            df.at[(curCommandIndex), 'command'] = curCommand
    
        # Index of current command grouping
        curCommandIndex = index
        # Starting building the full command and replace unecessary strings
        if row['command'].startswith("(command continued)"):
            curCommand = row['command'].replace("(command continued) ", "")
        elif row['command'].startswith("command="):
            curCommand = row['command'].replace("command=", "")
        else:
            curCommand = row['command']

    # Otherwise concat the commands together
    else: 
        if row['command'].startswith("(command continued)"):
            curCommand = curCommand + row['command'].replace("(command continued) ", "")    
        elif row['command'].startswith("command="):
            curCommand = curCommand + row['command'].replace("command=", "")
        else:
            curCommand = curCommand + row['command']
        # Drop the row after concating it onto the command
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)

    curAccount = row['account']
    curServer  = row['server']
```

Is there a faster, more pandas'esque, way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
command_starts = df['command'].str.startswith('command=')


df.assign(command=np.where(command_starts, df['command'].str[len('command='):],
                         df['command'].str[len('(command continued)'):]   
                        )
         ).groupby(command_starts.cumsum()).agg({
    'epoch':'first',
    'server':'first',
    'account':'first',
    'pwd': 'first',
    'command': ''.join
})
```

Output:

```
                 epoch   server account         pwd                                            command
command                                                                                               
1        1694030392144  server1     bob  /home/bob/  a bunch of commands here;  more commands here;...
2        1694030392149  server2     bob  /home/bob/                                      a new command
3        1694030392150  server3     bob  /home/bob/          I did something;  I did another thing WTF
4        1694030392152  server2    fred           /                                      a new command
5        1694030392153  server1    todd       /tmp/              I did something;  I did another thing
```